# Git push ignores directories that were added to project via git clone

Tags: git

Whenever I do classic routine:

```
git add -A
git commit -am "foo"
git push remote branch
```

Git doesn't upload files that were added via `git clone` command.

For example I cloned little project from github and included it as module into my project. But when I deployed it to the server via git, it only uploaded directory (folder) but nothing from inside, folder was empty.

How do I resolve this and why does that happen?

Comment: Do you have a gitinore file causing your dir to be omitted? When you added with -A, did the dir and its files show up as staged?

Comment: Wait, did you clone another repo inside of your existing local repo? If so, git ignores them. You might use submodules in that case.

Comment: @DavidN There is no `.gitignore` file. When I used `git add -A && git status` I remember that these two directories were colored red and there was `(modified)` sufix, while others were green.

Comment: @DavidN Yes I cloned github repo into existing git repo. I would use `rm -rf .git` command inside included repo.

Comment: Yea, so like I said, git will stop when it finds a .git dir in a subdir, so that explains it. Look at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules and consider if that can fit your needs.

Comment: @DavidN But even after removing `.git` from subdirectory, when I use `git add -A && git commit -am "foo" && git push` it still ignores it. Is there some cache to clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are under a git repository and clone another one inside, git will ignore the one inside when adding things from the parent one.

Basically git checks if every added folder has a `.git` folder inside. If you remove the `.git` folder from the sub-cloned folder you will be able to add that folder normally as if you copied the files manually

How to resolve this depends on what you want. Do you want to keep track of this sub-cloned repo and be able to pull and update it? If yes, then you need to take a look at git submodules. If not, just clone it, `rm -rf .git` and then add the folder.
But of course these two options are quite bad. You should consider using a dependency management tool (e.g cocoapods, npm, etc.)

Comment: Yeah I usually prefer `npm` but this specific plugin didn't have npm or anything similar. Even after using `rm -rf .git` that child directory is still ignored.

Comment: After removing `.git`, try to `git reset HEAD subfolder` and then `git add subfolder`. This time all the contents will be added, for sure.